# How to spell-check a Rich Text document?

Tags: spell-check, rtf, wordpad

I'm looking for a way to spell-check a Rich Text Document created with Wordpad on Windows 7.

I know no such feature exists within Wordpad, so I'm looking for workarounds. (I do not have a copy of Microsoft Word either.)

Simply pasting the text into an online spellchecker will not work, as I need to retain all the RTF data, like colors fonts and font size.

Does anyone know a way to do this?
THANKS

Comment: "I'm looking for a way to spell-check a Rich Text Document created with Wordpad on Windows 7." Use an Rich Text Document editor that has a spell check feature, lots of free open source solutions exist, I won't make any specific recommendations for obvious reasons.  The provided link offers non-software solutions though

Comment: @Ramhound - yup, thats what im looking for. Rich Text Document editor that has a spell check feature.

Comment: "If you don't see the spell check icon in the Rich Text Editor controls, then your administrator has disabled the intranet spell check in favor of using the built-in browser spell check. Chrome, FireFox, Safari, and some versions of Internet Explorer have built-in spell checkers that will underline misspelled words as you type. Press the CTRL key (or Command key) and right-click on a misspelled word to see a menu that includes spelling suggestions" - directly from the linked page....

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Software requests are off-topic, and the restrictions you're working within make software recommendations the only viable solutions. As such, Ramhound's suggestion is the correct answer.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I found 5 on the first result page when I did a Google search.

Comment: thanks, but i Googled this before coming to SA. Google is the easiest way, but I did not find anything that maintained my Rich Formatting when I pasted the text. As the original question stated "I need to retain all the RTF data, like colors fonts and font size." Also, @music2myear what do you mean 'Software requests are off-topic'? on other many SA sites (including Ask Ubunut, Super User and this site), we often recommend software that is useful for specific tasks.

Comment: If you're asking for software suggestions then it's off-topic. Ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead. And there are tons of free spell-checking products out there. Libreoffice is also free, no need for MS office

Comment: Stating a problem along with what you have tried so far and *then* getting a recommendation for a product is okay, but specifically asking for us to find software to perform a task is off topic. That is what people mean. Tell us about your journey, don't just ask for places to go.